# Ajax retornando dados repetidos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Sempre que uso Ajax para retornar um resultado do banco ele armazena esse resultado fazendo uma espécie de fila nas próximas requisições, retornando em outras consultas dados antigos junto aos atuais, exemplo...

```
$inputgetCod = (isset($_POST['codBarras'])) ? $_POST['codBarras'] : '';
...
else{

    $sql = 'SELECT nome,valorUnt from produtos where codigoBarras = ?';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(1, $inputgetCod);
    $stm->execute();
    $dads = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $vlt = $dads->valorUnt;
    $nm = $dads->nome;

    $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => 'cadastrado com sucesso', 'acerto' => $acerto, 'nome' => $nm, 'vlt' => $vlt);
            echo json_encode($retorno);
            exit();
}
```

Ajax

```
  var ajaxID = 0;
            $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '../phpVld/validaGetprod.php',
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache : false,
            success :  function(response){
$(".algumCampo").append(response.algum_dado);
}
```

quando chamo essa requisição novamente através de um botão ela retorna os dados antigos junto aos atuais, existe alguma forma de retornar somente dados de uma requisição por vez?

Comment: conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: consegui sim cara, foi mal n votar, na data da pergunta não sabia mexer muito no site

Comment: Normal, até hoje tem coisa que eu tenho dúvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque

```
$(".algumCampo").append(response.algum_dado);
```

por:

```
$(".algumCampo").text(response.algum_dado);
```

`append()` adicionará mais dados ao elemento, enquanto `text()` irá substituir pelo novo conteúdo